# How to verify a code snippet is present with Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I would like to check if the source code of the page contains the following:

```
background-color:#00FF00;border-color:#CCCCCC;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;width:14%;
```

The trick here is that it is part of an element without ID:

```
<td align="center" style="[see previous]">...</td>
```

What should be the command/target/value to accomplish this in Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The right command to use is [`verifyAttribute`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#storeAttribute).

Also, the ID is not the only way to find an element, you can also use [XPath or a CSS selector](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#locators), both will work for you.

Simply come up with the right XPath (or CSS selector), or use any automatic tool that does the job for you. If you record an action on the element in Selenium IDE, you'll see that it probably used an XPath expression to locate the element. Or if you right-click an element in Firebug, you'll see the options to copy the XPath or CSS selector, so use those.

An example:

```
verifyAttribute   xpath=//locator/to/your/element@style   background-color:#00FF00;border-color...
```

where the `@style` part of the locator is probably the only interesting part as it's a Selenium's convention to locate attributes.

---

**EDIT** addressing OP's comment:

> What I am trying to accomplish is check if the background of AT LEAST
>   ONE  in a given table (representing a calendar) has a green
>   background. Could you provide some guidance on how to achieve it?

Sure, I'd use [`assertElementPresent`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#storeElementPresent) with this XPath expression:

```
xpath=//table//td[contains(@style,'background-color:#00FF00')]
```

It returns all the `<td>` elements with green background stated in their `style` attribute.

The command then makes sure that at least one matching element is found on the page.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is check if the background of AT LEAST ONE <td> in a given table (representing a calendar) has a green background. Could you provide some guidance on how to achieve it?

Comment: @Pomario Sorry for the delay. I have just updated the answer.